# Как написать – раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Правильно ли писать *семейно ориентированный*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно раздельное написание: **семейно ориентированный**.

Так как здесь мы имеем что-то, ориентированное на семью, а не семейное и ориентированное. То есть это не сложное слово, а словосочетание, состоящее из наречия и прилагательного.

*Сложные прилагательные, первой частью которых является наречное слово и пишущиеся слитно, следует отличать от сочетаний, состоящих из наречия и прилагательного и пишущихся всегда раздельно. В таких сочетаниях наречия могут указывать на:

<...>

**определенное отношение, в котором рассматривается признак:** общественно полезный труд, социально опасный преступник, хозяйственно полезная деятельность, художественно полноценное произведение — наречие можно заменить сочетанием предлога для + существительное или словосочетанием с точки зрения + существительное (ср. соответственно: полезный для общества труд, опасный для общества преступник, полезная для хозяйства деятельность, полноценное с точки зрения художественности произведение);

<...>*

Answer (score 0):

По правилам русского языка  написание в текстах нейтрального стиля должно быть слитным, **но это термин,** и **в литературе соответствующей тематики его принято писать через дефис**: **семейно-ориентированный** подход в социально-педагогической работе

Например: [http://elib.bspu.by/bitstream/doc/14720/1/УМК%202016_СПР%20с%20семьей%20(1)-watermark.pdf](http://elib.bspu.by/bitstream/doc/14720/1/%D0%A3%D0%9C%D0%9A%202016_%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%A0%20%D1%81%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B9%20(1)-watermark.pdf)

http://www.sociologyinweb.ru/spgs-504-1.html

Аналогично пишется **личностно-ориентированный** подход.

https://studfiles.net/preview/5842044/

Comment: В ссылках, которые Вы привели, не значатся фамилии редакторов и корректоров. Там даже издательства не указаны. Из-за этого трудно оценить, насколько эти тексты грамотны и профессионально проверены. Что касается выражения **личностно ориентированный**, его раздельное написание зафиксировано в орфографическом словаре Лопатиных "Слитно, раздельно или через дефис?".

Comment: Да, зафиксировано, да, по общим правилам надо писать раздельно. Но в СПЕЦИАЛЬНОЙ  литературе используются не словосочетания, а ТЕРМИНЫ, принятые в данной области.  Здесь нужно обращать внимание не на издательства, а на сам документ, а это методики, рефераты и т.д.  Вряд ли научные работники безграмотны,  и тексты наверняка проверены корректором.  Эти термины имеют узкую область применения,  здесь  проявляется принцип "саморегулирования" орфографии. Чтобы убедиться в этом, надо изучить частотность использования терминов в официальной специальной литературе.

Comment: После таких противоположных мнений я теперь окончательно запуталась, как надо писать это слово. Хочется еще услышать мнения.

Comment: Спросите у Грамоты.ру, будет еще одно мнение. Скажите, что видели в документах дефисное написание, а по правилам надо писать раздельно.

Comment: Я задала этот вопрос на другом филологическом сайте. Вот ответ: Корректно раздельное написание (семейно ориентированный), так как это не сложное слово, а сочетание причастия и наречия образа действия: ориентированный (как?) семейно. Ср. зафиксированные в академическом орфографическом словаре написания  адресно ориентированный; аппаратно ориентированный;  личностно ориентированный и т. п. Теперь все встало на свои места.

Comment: Вам надо было не на филологический сайт обращаться, и так было понятно, что они скажут. Надо спрашивать у специалистов, которые пользуются этой терминологией, а филологи к этому отношения не имеют.  Кстати,  при дефисном написании мы имеем СЛОВО, а слова могут иметь пометку СПЕЦ.ЛЕКСИКА, и у них есть возможность не подчиняться общим правилам.  Вы сами попробуйте рассуждать логично: неужели студент или специалист будет делать ошибки в основной терминологии по своей специальности, а это один из основных терминов этой науки.